# custom div in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I new to reacts. I have used react-select to show dropdown. It works perfectly fine. Here is what I did for react-select:

```
<Select {...props}
          autoFocus={true}
          clearable={true}
          closeOnSelect={true}
          maxMenuHeight={300}
          escapeClearsValue={true}
          onBlurResetsInput={false} />
const props = {
  className: 'search-combobox',
  placeholder: 'Select value',
  onChange: some_method_call,
  onSelect: some_method_call,
  options: some_option_object,
  filterOptions: some_method_call,
  onInputChange: some_method_call,
  valueKey: 'id'
};
```

The above code snippet is giving some dropdown.

If I type something(e.g. the US), I will get some list in the dropdown(drop-down list will have to say 6/7 value like- student in the USA, list of students, ...)

So below every first drop down(i.e. student in the USA), I want to show some suggestions/filter-chunk like if I typing the US then I will get some suggestions/filter-chunk around 'US' like type: country, value: USA, type: student, value: Usain.

So How to achieve this using react-select?

My data for suggestions/filter-chunk is:

```
[
  {
    "type": "country",
    "value": "USA",
    "wordCount": 1,
    "value_match": true
  },
  {
    "type": "country",
    "value": "Sweden",
    "wordCount": 1,
    "value_match": false
  },
  {
    "type": "student",
    "value": "Usain",
    "wordCount": 1,
    "value_match": true
  }]
```

[image]

I am attaching a frame where if I type a list of us I'm able to get the sentence list(using react-select Select tag), but how to get that country, subject-id using the JSON array above?

Comment: Can you create some UX for what you have right now and what you want to enhance to. It is not clear from question exactly what you want.

Comment: I have attached an image

Comment: I think you can find the answer here : https://react-select.com/advanced#replacing-builtins